# Why are rmdir and unlink two separate system calls?

Tags: linux, directory, rm, system-calls

Here's something that kept me wondering for a while:

```
[15:40:50][/tmp]$ mkdir a
[15:40:52][/tmp]$ strace rmdir a
execve("/usr/bin/rmdir", ["rmdir", "a"], [/* 78 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x11bb000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff3772c3000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=245801, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 245801, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff377286000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\36\3428<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2100672, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3c38e00000, 3924576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c38e00000
mprotect(0x3c38fb4000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c391b4000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b4000) = 0x3c391b4000
mmap(0x3c391ba000, 16992, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3c391ba000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff377285000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff377283000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ff377283740) = 0
mprotect(0x609000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x3c391b4000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3c38c1f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7ff377286000, 245801)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x11bb000
brk(0x11dc000)                          = 0x11dc000
brk(0)                                  = 0x11dc000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106070960, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106070960, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff370d5a000
close(3)                                = 0
rmdir("a")                              = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
[15:40:55][/tmp]$ touch a
[15:41:16][/tmp]$ strace rm a
execve("/usr/bin/rm", ["rm", "a"], [/* 78 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xfa8000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3b2388a000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=245801, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 245801, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3b2384d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\36\3428<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2100672, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3c38e00000, 3924576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c38e00000
mprotect(0x3c38fb4000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c391b4000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b4000) = 0x3c391b4000
mmap(0x3c391ba000, 16992, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3c391ba000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3b2384c000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3b2384a000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f3b2384a740) = 0
mprotect(0x60d000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x3c391b4000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3c38c1f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f3b2384d000, 245801)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xfa8000
brk(0xfc9000)                           = 0xfc9000
brk(0)                                  = 0xfc9000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106070960, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106070960, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3b1d321000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "a", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "a", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "a", W_OK)          = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "a", 0)              = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Why are there separate system calls for removing a directory and files? Why would these two operations be semantically distinct?

Comment: Answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/430313/what-is-the-reason-for-rmdir1-and-rm1-to-co-exist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Directories are special in the sense that within a directory you can have references to several files and directories, so, if you remove the parent directory, all those files lose their reference point from where they can be accessed, the same with process. For such cases, `rmdir()` have different checks, that are different from `unlink()`:

- If the directory is not empty. If a directory is not empty it can't remove it until the contents are `unlink`'d/removed.

  > ```
  >    ENOTEMPTY
  >       pathname contains entries other than . and .. ; or, pathname has
  >       ..  as its final component.  POSIX.1-2001 also allows EEXIST for
  >       this condition.
  > ```
- If the directory is in use. If a process losses their current directory, it could lead to problems and undefined behaviors. Is better to prevent them.

  > ```
  >    EBUSY  pathname  is currently in use by the system or some process that
  >       prevents its removal.  On Linux this means pathname is currently
  >       used  as  a  mount point or is the root directory of the calling
  >       process.
  > ```

In the case of `unlink()` these checks doesn't exist. In fact, you can delete the name of a file with `unlink()` and the process that is still using/making reference to it, can modify it without problems. The file exist until the file descriptor exist, just unaccessible to new process (unless you know where to search). This is part of the rainbow-colored-hands magic of the *NIX file systems.

Now, there's the `unlinkat()` which behaves as both, `unlink()` or `rmdir(2)` depending the path which is what you expect.

Comment: Well `rm -rf "$PWD"` works and does remove the current directory. I think the reason there's a `rmdir()` is probably historical (initially, directories were unlinked() and rmdir (the command) was unlinking dir/., dir/.. and dir, and when that was moved to the kernel, that had to be a new syscall doing all 3 at least for a transition period or something like that)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas agree, that's why I added unlinkat.

Comment: If I read your answer properly, you're saying `rmdir(dir)` doesn't work if `dir` is in use. That is not true on Linux at least, where `rmdir(getcwd())` works just fine (provided the current directory is empty).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas correct, used by a process or as mount point: `EBUSY`  pathname  *is currently in use by the system or some process that
              prevents its removal*.  On Linux this means pathname is currently
              used  as  a  mount point or is the root directory of the calling
              process.

Comment: I'm not sure what they mean by _or is the root directory of the calling process_. `mkdir test; sudo strace -e chroot,rmdir perl -e 'chroot("test"); rmdir("test")'` shows both chroot and rmdir succeed.

Comment: Alright, that's `rmdir /` that returns EBUSY, removing it by another relative path (other than `.` and `..`) is OK (though that means your current directory must be outside the chroot jail which is generally not the case when chroot is used).

Comment: @Gilles, no, `chroot()` doesn't do a `chdir()`, so if your current directory was outside the jail before the chroot(), it still is after. That's why the literature  always says to close your references to things outside the jail when doing chroot, otherwise you can escape the jail. (see `man 2 chroot` on Linux for instance, and you can try it for yourself)

Comment: "rm -rf" worked/works because it uses rmdir(2) and unlink(2) under the covers based on the type of the target, file or directory.  Unlinkat() is arguably syntactic sugar, except for some handling of relative paths.

Comment: dbrower are you trying to ping @StéphaneChazelas?

Comment: This answer just begs the question. There's no technical reason why unlink() could not itself return ENOTEMPTY or EBUSY for directories so there would be no need for an additional rmdir() syscall.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from my personal wiki page [Why are unlink("/") And rmdir("/") Failing?](https://sourceforge.net/u/low-power/wiki/why-are-unlink-slash-and-rmdir-slash-failing/):

However there is a special file type – **directory**. Hard links to directories must be maintained in a consistent way to ensure correct operation of the file system; on modern Unix systems, several hard links will be automatically created or removed, when you create or remove a directory; for example when you create a directory at `/var/tmp/foo`, 2 hard links referring the new directory (inode) will be created at:

- `/var/tmp/foo` – the name itself you requested to create;
- `/var/tmp/foo/.` – the `.` name inside this new directory;

additonally another hard link referring to its parent directory will be create at `/var/tmp/foo/..`; thus a newly created directory will have link count of 2.

Ancient Unix systems allowing you to manually manipulate directory hard links; this is mostly used to rename a directory, because the **rename(2)** system call didn't exist back that days. To rename a directory, or a file with any other file type, manually, create a new name using **link(2)**, then remove the old name using **unlink(2)**; however operating directories using this approach is too often over-powered; users could easily introduce inconsistency to their file systems, by linking or unlinking directories inappropriately. For example creating a hard link where referring to any of its parent directories would result in infinite directory loop, or removing a directory hard link without first creating a link at somewhere else would making all files under that directory to be 'disconnected' from rest file system directory tree; those inconsistencies are expected to be detected by **fsck(8)** during next time system boot, but correctly fixing them is not guaranteed.

Unix systems provide **rmdir(2)** to correctly remove a directory, the inode, not only its primary hard link; using this system requiring the passed path referring a hard link that is not `.` or `..`, the hard link referring to a directory type inode, and the directory is empty, eg. containing only `.` and `..` links; a successful calling will remove these 2 hard links, the directory hard link specified by the path, as well as the directory inode.