# Why is it rm -rf and not rmdir -rf

Tags: shell, files, directory

I've always been curious why the command for deleting everything in a directory is `rm -rf`.

Why aren't there flags to do the same thing with `rmdir`?

Wouldn't it be more intuitive to use `rmdir` for directory operations?

Comment: `rmdir` removes directories, `rm` removes. Why would it be intuitive for `rmdir` to remove non-directories?

Comment: Because it isn't. You're 40-something years late asking this question, and you're asking the wrong people.

Answer (score 27):

In the early Unix File System (at least back in the V7 days circa 1970) directories were implemented as special files and only root could use the `mknod(2)` system call that created them and only root could `unlink(2)` a directory special file.

These protections were in place in order to keep the filesystem structure consistent. For example, if a user was allowed to write to a directory special file, he could make its parent directory `..` point to itself (specifically its own i-node). This would create a circular reference in the filesystem which would be a Bad Thing. Of course there are other inconsistencies one could make, this is just a clear example.

The consistency was maintained by user-space programs like `mkdir(1)` and `rmdir(1)` which were Set-UID root so that they could make the privileged system calls on behalf of an unprivileged user. When recursion was added to `rm(1)`, the remove command would run as the current UID and then call out to `rmdir(1)` solely for removing empty directories. This is still a pretty standard method of elevation of permission: don't use more permissions than you need.

Sometime later `mkdir(2)` and `rmdir(2)` were added as their own system calls but the relation between `rm(1)` and `rmdir(1)` remains.

Personally, I find it a tad more satisfying to `rmdir junk` and know that the worst I did was remove an empty directory.

Comment: Re the last sentence: Presumably, if the recursive delete operation was in `rmdir`, it would still need a `-r` flag. (`rmdir -r junk` instead of `rm -r junk`, and `rmdir junk` still only works if the directory is empty)

Answer (score 7):

It's historical.  `rm` was made to remove the references to files, `rmdir` was made to remove directories, parallel to `mkdir`.  Many years ago, Unix `rm` could only remove directories by invoking `rmdir`.  There also wasn't an `rmdir(2)` system call, `rmdir` was a program that called `unlink(2)`.

References:

- [What is the reason for rmdir(1) and rm(1) to co-exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/430313/what-is-the-reason-for-rmdir1-and-rm1-to-co-exist)
- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/issue49/fischer.html
- [Why are rmdir and unlink two separate system calls?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150960/why-are-rmdir-and-unlink-two-separate-system-calls)

Answer (score 2):

Purely a matter of opinion, but `rm` removes files while `rmdir` removes directories. A directory is a file, but a special type of file, so it makes sense for `rm` to remove them, but to treat them specially (i.e. to require an extra option to enable the capability.) On the other hand not all files are directories, and it makes no sense IMHO for `rmdir` to remove something that isn't a directory.

Comment: If that was the case, then why can't `rm` remove an empty directory (except in recursive mode)?

Comment: Same reason it can't remove a full directory - it requires the `-r` flag to enable the directory special-file feature.

Comment: Circular reasoning there...

Comment: I'd say my reasoning has an eccentricity >> 1...